# how to use CDPSession with puppeteersharp intercept request

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

all

I used puppeteersharp ,need to intercept  request and response, when use blow code:

```
page.Response += OnPageResponse,
```

when the url is Navigation,cannot get the content,the  error:

```
 Unable to get response body ---> PuppeteerSharp.MessageException: Protocol error (Network.getResponseBody): No resource with given identifier found
```

error report link:https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2258

that link gvie a article around that erorr:
Using Chrome Devtools Protocol with Puppeteer
https://medium.com/@jsoverson/using-chrome-devtools-protocol-with-puppeteer-737a1300bac0

but use Chrome Devtools Protocol with PuppeteerSharp,I meet error:

```
Invalid parameters patterns: array expected
```

when set arg:

```
object oo = new { urlPattern = "*", resourceType = "Script", interceptionStage = "HeadersReceived" };
                        object arg = "{ patterns: [{urlPattern: '*.js*',resourceType: 'Script',interceptionStage: 'HeadersReceived'}] }";
                        arg = "{ patterns: [{urlPattern='*.js*',resourceType='Script',interceptionStage='HeadersReceived'}] }";
                        arg = "{ patterns: [{urlPattern=\"*.js*\",resourceType=\"Script\",interceptionStage=\"HeadersReceived\"}] }";
                        arg = "{ patterns: [{urlPattern:\"*.js*\",resourceType:\"Script\",interceptionStage:\"HeadersReceived\"}] }";
                        arg = "[{urlPattern:\"*.js*\",resourceType:\"Script\",interceptionStage:\"HeadersReceived\"}]";
                        arg = "[{urlPattern=\"*.js*\",resourceType=\"Script\",interceptionStage=\"HeadersReceived\"}]";

                        Console.WriteLine("arg:" + arg);

                        tjj = cdp.SendAsync("Network.setRequestInterception", arg);
```

Above is all format i tested , all is error, so what the arg format?

thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code using intercept request and response. That should work...

Comment: hi,i used:Task t = page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);
                        t.Wait();
                        page.Request += pagepojo.OnPageRequest;
                        page.Response += pagepojo.OnPageResponse;
                        page.RequestFinished += pagepojo.OnRequestFinished;

Comment: That has a question,when the url is Navigation, then cannot get the response, errormsg: Unable to get response body ---> PuppeteerSharp.MessageException: Protocol error (Network.getResponseBody): No resource with given identifier found

Comment: @hardkoded then is find  use Chrome Devtools Protocol   can do this, but i donot know how to make arg . https://medium.com/@jsoverson/using-chrome-devtools-protocol-with-puppeteer-737a1300bac0

Comment: `Network.setRequestInterception` is old. Pupppeteer-Sharp uses `Fetch.enable` internally. I suggest trying to use the API instead of sending raw messages.

Comment: @hardkoded can give same example？ thanks for rep.

Comment: You can get many examples from there https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp.Tests/NetworkTests/SetRequestInterceptionTests.cs :)

Comment: @hardkoded  i viewed this page,but cannot solve my problem.i will find msg for Fetch.enable, thanks.

Comment: @hardkoded Fetch.enable is puppeteersharp used now, but this has a bug, report 
 link:https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2258, is there any data for use Chrome Devtools Protocol with puppeteersharp ?